# Remove Shipping Method and Payment Method from invoice pdf in Magento

Tags: php, magento, pdf, invoice

I wanto completely remove the `Shipping Method` and `Payment Method` section from **invoice pdf** in `Magento`.

My `invoice pdf` is look like this:

[image]

I look the `app/code/core/mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php` file, here I can change the labels but I can't change the table(boxes).

Please help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I can change the app/code/core/mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php file,Replace the below code,

```
protected function insertOrder(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true)
    {
        if ($obj instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order) {
            $shipment = null;
            $order = $obj;
        } elseif ($obj instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment) {
            $shipment = $obj;
            $order = $shipment->getOrder();
        }

        $this->y = $this->y ? $this->y : 815;
        $top = $this->y;

        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.45));
        $page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.45));
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 570, $top - 55);
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $this->setDocHeaderCoordinates(array(25, $top, 570, $top - 55));
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);

        if ($putOrderId) {
            $page->drawText(
                Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order # ') . $order->getRealOrderId(), 35, ($top -= 30), 'UTF-8'
            );
        }
        $page->drawText(
            Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Date: ') . Mage::helper('core')->formatDate(
                $order->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), 'medium', false
            ),
            35,
            ($top -= 15),
            'UTF-8'
        );

        $top -= 10;
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 275, ($top - 25));
        $page->drawRectangle(275, $top, 570, ($top - 25));

        /* Calculate blocks info */

        /* Billing Address */
        $billingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($order->getBillingAddress()->format('pdf'));

        /* Payment */
        $paymentInfo = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())
            ->setIsSecureMode(true)
            ->toPdf();
        $paymentInfo = htmlspecialchars_decode($paymentInfo, ENT_QUOTES);
        $payment = explode('{{pdf_row_separator}}', $paymentInfo);
        foreach ($payment as $key=>$value){
            if (strip_tags(trim($value)) == '') {
                unset($payment[$key]);
            }
        }
        reset($payment);

        /* Shipping Address and Method */
        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            /* Shipping Address */
            $shippingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($order->getShippingAddress()->format('pdf'));
            $shippingMethod  = $order->getShippingDescription();
        }

        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
        $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Sold to:'), 35, ($top - 15), 'UTF-8');

        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to:'), 285, ($top - 15), 'UTF-8');
        } 

        $addressesHeight = $this->_calcAddressHeight($billingAddress);
        if (isset($shippingAddress)) {
            $addressesHeight = max($addressesHeight, $this->_calcAddressHeight($shippingAddress));
        }

        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $page->drawRectangle(25, ($top - 25), 570, $top - 33 - $addressesHeight);
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $this->y = $top - 40;
        $addressesStartY = $this->y;

        foreach ($billingAddress as $value){
            if ($value !== '') {
                $text = array();
                foreach (Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                    $text[] = $_value;
                }
                foreach ($text as $part) {
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($part)), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                    $this->y -= 15;
                }
            }
        }

        $addressesEndY = $this->y;

        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $this->y = $addressesStartY;
            foreach ($shippingAddress as $value){
                if ($value!=='') {
                    $text = array();
                    foreach (Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                        $text[] = $_value;
                    }
                    foreach ($text as $part) {
                        $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($part)), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                        $this->y -= 15;
                    }
                }
            }

            $addressesEndY = min($addressesEndY, $this->y);
            $this->y = $addressesEndY;

            // $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
            // $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
            // $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 275, $this->y-25);
            // $page->drawRectangle(275, $this->y, 570, $this->y-25);

            $this->y -= 15;
            $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
            $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
            // $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment Method'), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            // $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Method:'), 285, $this->y , 'UTF-8');

            $this->y -=10;
            $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));

            $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
            $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));

            $paymentLeft = 35;
            $yPayments   = $this->y - 15;
        }
        else {
            $yPayments   = $addressesStartY;
            $paymentLeft = 285;
        }

        // foreach ($payment as $value){
            // if (trim($value) != '') {
                // //Printing "Payment Method" lines
                // $value = preg_replace('/<br[^>]*>/i', "\n", $value);
                // foreach (Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                    // $page->drawText(strip_tags(trim($_value)), $paymentLeft, $yPayments, 'UTF-8');
                    // $yPayments -= 15;
                // }
            // }
        // }

        if ($order->getIsVirtual()) {
            // replacement of Shipments-Payments rectangle block
            $yPayments = min($addressesEndY, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(25,  ($top - 25), 25,  $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(570, ($top - 25), 570, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(25,  $yPayments,  570, $yPayments);

            $this->y = $yPayments - 15;
        // } else {
            $topMargin    = 15;
            $methodStartY = $this->y;
            $this->y     -= 15;

            // foreach (Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($shippingMethod, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                // $page->drawText(strip_tags(trim($_value)), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                // $this->y -= 15;
            // }

            $yShipments = $this->y;
            // $totalShippingChargesText = "(" . Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total Shipping Charges') . " "
                // . $order->formatPriceTxt($order->getShippingAmount()) . ")";

            // $page->drawText($totalShippingChargesText, 285, $yShipments - $topMargin, 'UTF-8');
            // $yShipments -= $topMargin + 10;

            // $tracks = array();
            // if ($shipment) {
                // $tracks = $shipment->getAllTracks();
            // }
            // if (count($tracks)) {
                // $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
                // $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
                // $page->drawRectangle(285, $yShipments, 510, $yShipments - 10);
                // $page->drawLine(400, $yShipments, 400, $yShipments - 10);
                // //$page->drawLine(510, $yShipments, 510, $yShipments - 10);

                // $this->_setFontRegular($page, 9);
                // $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
                // //$page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Carrier'), 290, $yShipments - 7 , 'UTF-8');
                // $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Title'), 290, $yShipments - 7, 'UTF-8');
                // $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Number'), 410, $yShipments - 7, 'UTF-8');

                // $yShipments -= 20;
                // $this->_setFontRegular($page, 8);
                // foreach ($tracks as $track) {

                    // $CarrierCode = $track->getCarrierCode();
                    // if ($CarrierCode != 'custom') {
                        // $carrier = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getCarrierInstance($CarrierCode);
                        // $carrierTitle = $carrier->getConfigData('title');
                    // } else {
                        // $carrierTitle = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Custom Value');
                    // }

                    // //$truncatedCarrierTitle = substr($carrierTitle, 0, 35) . (strlen($carrierTitle) > 35 ? '...' : '');
                    // $maxTitleLen = 45;
                    // $endOfTitle = strlen($track->getTitle()) > $maxTitleLen ? '...' : '';
                    // $truncatedTitle = substr($track->getTitle(), 0, $maxTitleLen) . $endOfTitle;
                    // //$page->drawText($truncatedCarrierTitle, 285, $yShipments , 'UTF-8');
                    // $page->drawText($truncatedTitle, 292, $yShipments , 'UTF-8');
                    // $page->drawText($track->getNumber(), 410, $yShipments , 'UTF-8');
                    // $yShipments -= $topMargin - 5;
                // }
            // } else {
                // $yShipments -= $topMargin - 5;
            // }

            $currentY = min($yPayments, $yShipments);

            // replacement of Shipments-Payments rectangle block
            $page->drawLine(25,  $methodStartY, 25,  $currentY); //left
            $page->drawLine(25,  $currentY,     570, $currentY); //bottom
            $page->drawLine(570, $currentY,     570, $methodStartY); //right

            $this->y = $currentY;
            $this->y -= 15;
        }
    }
```

Comment: one more question..The products list in the pdf are as plain, how can I provide border or table etc..You can refer the image in my question.

Comment: By default there is no border,you have to customize.